# How to hide keybord while typing in iphone app

Tags: iphone

I have 2 textview one is on top and other is at bottom. When I am trying to write something on bottom textview keyboard is coming on screen and I am not able to see what I am typing.

How to make keyboard invisible or placed on perfect place while typing below textview?

Comment: How do you type if keyboard is invisible ??

Comment: You need to move your view up when bottom textView start editing.

Comment: @Deepak, I don't want to hide keyboard. But I want to type anyhow. @"jampag" How will I up my view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Answer to your problem lies here buddy..

[Sliding UITextFeilds when keyboard appears](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/sliding-uitextfields-around-to-avoid.html)

Its Best solution available.

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    if (textView == bottomTextView) {
        CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
        frame.origin.y -= 250;
        self.view.frame = frame;
    }
}

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    if (textView == bottomTextView) {
        CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
        frame.origin.y += 250;
        self.view.frame = frame;
    }
}
```

You can modify this `250` value.

Answer (score 1):

### Write This Delegate Methods For TextField

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

if (textField == txtUserName) {
    [txtUserName becomeFirstResponder];     
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,45) animated:YES];
} else if (textField == txtPassword) {
    [txtPassword becomeFirstResponder];     
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,105) animated:YES];
}
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
[textField resignFirstResponder];
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0) animated:YES];
return YES;
}
```